# error when passing rss feed to php domDocument object

Tags: php, xml, google-api, feed, domdocument

can anyone possibly point me in the right direction

I am using curl to get back a google picasa api feed.
This all works well, with the autorisation and the fetching of the data,
but now I want to expand a little bit in try'n to add,update tags,pics, geo-info from my site.

How can I pass the feed I got back with curl to the domDocument somehow??

this did not work

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xml = $dom->load(trim($feed )); 
or
 $xml = $dom->loadXML($feed);
```

if I echo it directly I get an rss page in FF

```
echo trim($feed );
```

but

```
echo $xml;
```

will give a xml parse syntax error?

Also, if anyone has any links to work with google-api for PUT, DELETE, UPDATE operations
that is not related to ZEND, but uses a different PHP approach, curl or something, that would be great.(code that's easyer to follow)

thanks, Richard

Comment: Why did your code not work, do you get an error message?

Comment: Can you post an example of $feed?

Answer (score 1):

Use     `$feed = simplexml_load_string($feedXml);`

Comment: thanks, I know that that works because I fetch the data like that, but I also have to make new xml to update to the api. I thought it was neccesary to use domdocument for that?